# How can i download this link using curl and php

Tags: php, php-curl

cannot download this link using curl php
https://www.economy.gov.ae/PublicationsArabic/2%20%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF%20199-%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1%20%D8%B9%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9.pdf

tried basic curl didn't work, wget don't work too

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "utf-8");
 echo $output=curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
```

empty pdf or 189 byte

Comment: don't use the curl here, use file_get_content function instead

Comment: from my machine, wget works fine...

Comment: did you get 30mo pdf wget get only a 189 byte non readable pdf

Comment: what are you talking about, anyway i found out the problem, it was a post request that is needed before that get request, when you do that this code work right, thank you for the help anyway

Comment: try to see that on network tab

Answer (score 0):

just website use post request before that get request and you need to forge it before as it has a certain logic on app, now it work right

Answer (score -1):

Try `urldecode` before using curl:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = urldecode($url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "utf-8");
 echo $output=curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: sorry i just copy pasted that part

Comment: it is already url encoded, or you can learn what url encode is